# Sum of two values using ndk android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have successfully run my jni sample.Now i am trying to add two values but its sum is not proper.I am sharing my code.Please tell me what wrong i am doing

```
 jint Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_sumTwoValues( JNIEnv* env,jint a, jint b){
//_android_log_print("HelloJni", "values a", "%p", &a);

    __android_log_print("HelloJni", "LOG_TAG", "Need to print : %d %d",a, b);
    return (a+b);
 }
```

And how i am calling this method from my activity is as follows.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Create a TextView and set its content.
     * the text is retrieved by calling a native
     * function.
     */
    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Sum is ."+ sumTwoValues(15,7));
    setContentView(tv);
}



/* A native method that is implemented by the
 * 'hellojni' native library, which is packaged
 * with this application.
 */

public native int sumTwoValues(int a,int b);


// Loading 'hellojni' 

static {
    System.loadLibrary("hellojni");
}
```

And text of Textview is not fixed.its different every time i run. ex of sum i have is 363855916

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like

```
jint Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_sumTwoValues( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jint a, jint b){
//_android_log_print("HelloJni", "values a", "%p", &a);

    __android_log_print("HelloJni", "LOG_TAG", "Need to print : %d %d",a, b);
    return (a+b);
 }
```

**B'coz you define**

`public native int sumTwoValues(int a,int b);` as non static

**and if**

```
public native static int sumTwoValues(int a,int b); static method
```

Then use `jclass` instead of `jobject`

Comment: can u please tell me what type of value native method use when we don't add jobject as argument.

Comment: @Manmohan if you declare native method as Non-Static use jobject or if using static use jclass. Its coding convension that you need to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the JNI code snippet

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_example_ndk_NativeLib_add
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint value1, jint value2) {
        return (value1 + value2);
}
```

Create one class to access this method `NativeLib.java`

```
public class NativeLib {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ndk");
    }

    /**
     * Adds two integers, returning their sum
     */
    public native int add(int v1, int v2);
}
```

And in `MainActivity.java` onCreate

```
nativeLib = new NativeLib();
res = nativeLib.add(v1, v2);
result.setText(new Integer(res).toString());
```

You can find the complete demo from below link

http://junedk.blogspot.in/2014/01/ndk-sum-of-two-values.html

Answer (score 0):

Write your function's code like this. It should give proper return value.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_sumTwoValues(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj, jint a, jint b)
{
       //_android_log_print("HelloJni", "values a", "%p", &a);
       jint total=(a+b);
      __android_log_print("HelloJni", "LOG_TAG", "Need to print : %d %d",a, b);
      return total;

}
```

Comment: I have tried to print a,b value using android_log_print.Their a,b not have values i  passed using method in console. it is like this 01-16 02:26:48.267: I/System.out(1123): Need to print : 505413661 154251451

Answer (score 0):

Add c/c++ file in CMakeLists.txt

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

```
         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).

          **src/main/c/add.c**)
```